# Spring Eureka cluster replication issues [version eureka-Brixton.SR1]

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am trying to setup a eureka cluster which comprise of there servers. (my setup is on local machine)

Configurations for each eureka server as below:

server1:

```
server:
  port: 8764
eureka:
  instance:
     metadataMap:
       instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    # availabilityZones: zone1,zone1,zone1
  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
    serviceUrl:
     defaultZone: http://localhost:8762/eureka/,http://localhost:8763/eureka/,http://localhost:8764/eureka/
```

server2:

```
server:
  port: 8762
eureka:
  instance:
     metadataMap:
       instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8762/eureka/,http://localhost:8763/eureka/,http://localhost:8764/eureka/
```

server3:

```
server:
  port: 8763

eureka:
  instance:
     metadataMap:
       instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8762/eureka/,http://localhost:8763/eureka/,http://localhost:8764/eureka/
```

each server is peering to each others, so registration info will be replicated among servsers.

But, when I checked the logs server, it always throw exception as beblow:

[image]

I also checked dashboard of eureka server and it shown as below:

[image]

I dont know why the registered replicas (**http://localhost:8761/eureka/**) did not change even I have configured

```
serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8762/eureka/,http://localhost:8763/eureka/,http://localhost:8764/eureka/
```

I have setup a micro services and register to the eureka cluster, but for somehow the service info only is registered on one of eureak server, I am expecting that info also replicated to others as well

is there anyone suffering from same issue, I have been trying searching a lot but could not find the right answer for my case.

High appreicate for any advice?

Comment: Can you try with something newer? Dalston.SR1 is the latest.

Comment: can you advise where I can get the bin distribution of the latest version as I dont want to build from sourcecode; I am in a corporate network so there are a lot of restriction. @spencergibb

Comment: We don't offer a packaged download. Maven central is where all of the binaries are.

Comment: it still connect to `http://localhost:8761/eureka`  and saying connection timeout

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issues. I have put serviceUrl in wrong section (server).

it should be in the client part.

```
server:
  port: 8763

eureka:
  instance:
     metadataMap:
       instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
   serviceUrl:
      defaultZone:     http://localhost:8762/eureka/,http://localhost:8763/eureka/,http://localhost:876
  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
```